# Predicting values based on previous values from same column and surrounding data in R

Tags: r

I have a database of law projects, which has like 20 columns, categorical and numeric, about the law projects themselves (politicians, chamber it came from, topic, parties involved, political context, gender distribution of their sponsors, etc.). One of those columns is the date of creation of the projects, too.

Some projects have already been voted and published as law, therefore I know how long it took them to be approved (in days).

I want to predict how long it will take to publish the non-published projects, based on the surrounding data.

In other words, I need to use the published projects as training data, and the non-published as data I need predictions on, based on the fact that published projects have numbers on “days” (for publishing) column, and the non-published don’t.

How can I make this prediction?

Below is a sample data frame of 20 rows, 10 with `published == TRUE` and 10 with `published == FALSE`, and the column I need to predict is `days`

```
data.frame(
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               date = c("1992-09-16","2006-07-12",
                        "2016-06-02","2015-11-25","2017-04-06","1993-07-08",
                        "2001-04-04","2012-03-14","2014-11-17","2020-03-18",
                        "2011-11-24","2006-07-20","2016-08-11","2019-01-25",
                        "2007-12-17","2015-08-13","2008-12-18","2012-08-14",
                        "2017-10-17","2014-05-14"),
         project_id = c("799-15","4332-15",
                        "10728-07","10422-06","11188-17","1034-15","2686-15",
                        "8201-09","9729-03","13318-07","8062-07","4357-15",
                        "10856-11","12434-07","5583-07","10259-18","6285-07",
                        "8525-18","11481-07","9352-11"),
      project_title = c("Sustituye el Artí­culo 18 de la Nº 18.290, de Tránsito, en lo relativo a la duración de la licencia de conducir.",
                        "Concede permiso para trabajadores al interior de la locomoción colectiva.",
                        "Modifica la Carta Fundamental con el objeto de cambiar la fecha de la cuenta que efectúa la Presidenta de la República sobre el estado administrativo y polí­tico de la Nación",
                        "Reemplaza el artí­culo 111 de la Carta Fundamental, en materia de gobierno regional e instituye la elección de los intendentes mediante sufragio universal.",
                        "Modifica la ley Nº19.253, que Establece normas sobre protección, fomento y desarrollo de los indí­genas, y crea la Corporación Nacional de Desarrollo Indí­gena, para reconocer al pueblo chango como etnia indí­gena de Chile",
                        "Modifica la Ley Nº 18.290, con la finalidad de establecer la obigatoriedad de realizar licitaciones públicas de establecimientos que practiquen revisiones técnicas de vehí­culos motorizados en todas las comunas del paí­s.",
                        "Establece un seguro obligatorio de accidentes personales causados por circulación de vehí­culos motorizados.",
                        "Sobre medidas de seguridad en pasarelas, pasos sobre nivel y puentes que cruzan carreteras.",
                        "Modifica la ley Nº 19.496, que establece normas sobre protección de los derechos de los consumidores, con el objeto de regular el cobro del servicio de parquí­metros y estacionamientos en los lugares que indica.",
                        "Proyecto de reforma constitucional que autoriza al Congreso Nacional a sesionar por medios telemáticos en los casos que indica",
                        "Reforma Constitucional que restablece obligatoriedad del voto.",
                        "Agrega nuevo inciso al artí­culo 46 de la ley Nº 18.290, referido a los colores, forma y dimensiones de las placas únicas contempladas en la ley de tránsito.",
                        "Modifica la ley Nº19.925, Sobre expendio y consumo de bebidas alcohólicas, para sancionar con mayor severidad las infracciones a la prohibición establecida en protección de los menores de edad",
                        "Modifica la ley Nº 18.918, orgánica constitucional del Congreso Nacional, para regular los efectos del permiso por paternidad en el cómputo de quórum y mayorí­as",
                        "Regula el ejercicio del derecho a reunirse pací­ficamente.",
                        "Crea el Registro Nacional de Deudores de Pensiones Alimenticias.",
                        "Modifica el Código Civil respecto de los delitos y cuasidelitos civiles cometidos por menores de edad.",
                        "Establece efectos civiles y penales por la comisión del delito de maltrato habitual de la ley Nº20.066.",
                        "Modifica el Código Procesal Penal, para regular la revocación del acuerdo reparatorio.",
                        "Modifica Código Sanitario, a fin de sancionar a quien administre o posea, vertedero clandestino."),
             status = c("Publicado","Publicado",
                        "Publicado","Publicado","Publicado","Publicado",
                        "Publicado","Publicado","Publicado","Publicado",
                        "En tramitación","En tramitación","En tramitación",
                        "En tramitación","Archivado","En tramitación","En tramitación",
                        "En tramitación","En tramitación","Archivado"),
              topic = c("Obras Públicas, Transportes y Telecomunicaciones.",
                        "Obras Públicas, Transportes y Telecomunicaciones.",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento",
                        "Gobierno Interior, Nacionalidad, Ciudadanía y Regionalización",
                        "Derechos Humanos, Nacionalidad y Ciudadanía",
                        "Obras Públicas, Transportes y Telecomunicaciones.",
                        "Obras Públicas, Transportes y Telecomunicaciones.","Recursos Hídricos, Desertificación y Sequía",
                        "Economía, Fomento, Micro, Pequeña y Mediana Empresa, Protección de los Consumidores y Turismo",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento",
                        "Obras Públicas, Transportes y Telecomunicaciones.","Salud",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento","De la Familia",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento",
                        "De la Familia",
                        "Constitución, Legislación, Justicia y Reglamento","Salud"),
          published = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,
                        TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,
                        FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
               days = c("4833","1214","336","407",
                        "1290","4538","866","817","731","8",NA,NA,NA,
                        NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
              cargo = c("Senador","Senador",
                        "Diputado","Senador","Diputado","Senador","Senador",
                        "Senador","Diputado","Senador","Diputado","Senador",
                        "Diputado","Senador","Senador","Diputado","Diputado",
                        "Diputado","Senador","Senador"),
             genero = c("M","M","M","M","F","M",
                        "M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","M","F","M",
                        "M","M","M"),
            partido = c("UDI","Independiente","UDI",
                        "RN","PC","UDI","RN","UDI","DC","PS","DC","DC",
                        "PC","PPD","Pais Progresista","PC","PPD","RN",
                        "Independiente","Independiente"),
             region = c("Región del Maule",
                        "Región de Antofagasta","Región Metropolitana de Santiago",
                        "Región de la Araucanía","Región Metropolitana de Santiago",
                        "Región del Maule","Región de la Araucanía",
                        "Región del Libertador General Bernardo O'Higgins",
                        "Región de Los Ríos","Región del Maule","Región de Ñuble",
                        "Región de Magallanes y la Antártica Chilena",
                        "Región Metropolitana de Santiago","Región del Biobío",
                        "Región del Biobío","Región Metropolitana de Santiago",
                        "Región de Valparaíso","Región de Ñuble","Región de Antofagasta",
                        "Región de Magallanes y la Antártica Chilena"),
           distrito = c(9,3,14,11,9,9,11,8,24,
                        9,19,15,9,10,10,9,7,19,3,15),
          ideologia = c(3,0,3,3,-3,3,3,3,1,
                        -2,1,1,-3,0,-1,-3,0,3,0,0),
      fecha_ingreso = c("1992-09-16","2006-07-12",
                        "2016-06-02","2015-11-25","2017-04-06","1993-07-08",
                        "2001-04-04","2012-03-14","2014-11-17","2020-03-18",
                        NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
         iniciativa = c("Moción","Moción","Moción",
                        "Moción","Moción","Moción","Moción","Moción",
                        "Moción","Moción",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
              n_ley = c("Ley Nº 20.068",
                        "Ley Nº 20.388","Ley N° 21.011","Ley N° 20.990","Ley N° 21.273",
                        "Ley Nº 20.068","Ley Nº 19.887","Ley N° 20.753",
                        "Ley N° 20.967","Ley N° 21.219",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                        NA,NA,NA),
  fecha_publicacion = c("2005-12-10","2009-11-07",
                        "2017-05-04","2017-01-05","2020-10-17","2005-12-10",
                        "2003-08-18","2014-06-09","2016-11-17","2020-03-26",
                        NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
            aprueba = c(NA,0.588609625988215,
                        0.239293203926262,0.239293203926262,0.198232587727645,NA,
                        0.486342468349014,0.227811246640991,0.378658817614279,
                        0.0602900629256258,0.263274470108713,0.45791429449014,
                        0.239293203926262,0.365168783759783,0.388320501421412,
                        0.28639908396031,0.429509630187767,0.235967915643678,
                        0.225057300910334,0.342202303911118),
         desaprueba = c(NA,0.226933127280144,
                        0.580545109188936,0.580545109188936,0.600041245494515,NA,
                        0.262920553958243,0.619839921565968,0.430880155305093,
                        0.822159297111715,0.525507754836235,0.305382056498538,
                        0.580545109188936,0.391162345818584,0.421119293586968,
                        0.556417403359417,0.38144207967139,0.592325472064253,
                        0.534274514219923,0.462000911671922),
         alineacion = c("Oposición","Independiente",
                        "Oposición","Oposición","Oficialismo","Oposición",
                        "Oposición","Oficialismo","Oficialismo","Oposición",
                        "Oposición","Oficialismo","Oficialismo","Oposición",
                        NA,"Oficialismo","Oficialismo","Oficialismo",
                        "Independiente","Independiente"),
           personas = c(2L,3L,7L,2L,5L,2L,1L,
                        1L,4L,1L,5L,2L,5L,9L,1L,7L,3L,1L,1L,2L),
          oposicion = c(1,NA,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
                        NA,0,0.2,0.444444444444444,NA,NA,0,0,0,0.5),
        oficialismo = c(0,NA,0,0,1,0,0,1,0.75,
                        0,NA,0.5,0.8,0.444444444444444,NA,NA,1,1,0,0),
         diversidad = c(0.5,1,0.142857142857143,1,
                        0.8,0.5,1,1,0.5,1,0.6,1,1,0.777777777777778,1,
                        0.857142857142857,0.333333333333333,1,1,1),
        transversal = c(0,0.666666666666667,0,0,0,
                        0,0,0,0.25,0,0.4,0.5,0.2,0.222222222222222,0,
                        0.142857142857143,0,0,0,0.5),
            paridad = c(0,0.33,0.14,0.5,0.6,0,0,
                        0,0,0,0.2,0.5,0.4,1,0,0.71,0.33,0,0,0),
        centralismo = c(0.5,0,0.43,0,0.4,0.5,0,
                        0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.44,0,0.29,0,0,0,0),
              apoyo = c(0.857142857142857,
                        0.937134909596662,1.40637813211845,0.397354974451458,
                        0.92295526434704,0.909090909090909,0.484162895927602,
                        0.221837549933422,0.807683716774626,0.133712528823982,
                        1.15158564956532,0.624756606397775,1.00455580865604,
                        1.15672464313557,0.312020460358056,1.3907424105801,
                        0.883169462116831,0.221837549933422,0.184591052869408,
                        0.403841858387313)
)
```

Comment: This might help get you started: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/

Answer (score 1):

To use the published projects as training data, you can filter by `published == TRUE`. For example:

```
trainset <- data %>% filter(published == TRUE)
testset <- data %>% filter(published == FALSE)
```

Alternatively, if you want to split the training and testing datasets using the `days` column, you can use:

```
trainset <- data[!is.na(data$days),]
testset <- data[is.na(data$days),]
```

You can create a linear regression model and view the model output using:

```
linear_model <- lm(days ~ [chosen variable/s here], data = trainset)
summary(linear_model)
```

See the documentation here (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/predict.lm) for making predictions on new data using the predict.lm function.